# Z axis position in a 3D plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d, axis

I probably missed it on [pgfplots.sourceforge](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/gallery.html) but how can I have the `z axis` positioned as the red and not in front ?

[image]

MWE

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfplotsset{colormap={whitered}{color(0cm)=(white!20!orange); color(2.5cm)=(orange!75!red)}}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
    view={-30}{30},
    axis lines=center,  %% of course it's not center i need.
    axis on top,
    axis line style={black!40},
    xlabel style ={sloped},
    ylabel style ={sloped},
    ticklabel style={font=\small},
    samples=31]

    \addplot3 [surf,opacity=0.2]    {exp(-x^2-y^2)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture} 
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `axis lines=left` instead of `axis lines=center`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
group style={group size=3 by 2, vertical sep=10ex,  horizontal sep=6ex},
view={-30}{30},
axis lines=left,  
axis on top,
axis line style={black!40},
xlabel style ={sloped},
ylabel style ={sloped},
ticklabel style={font=\small},
domain=50:150,
y domain=0.01:1, 
samples=11]
\nextgroupplot
\addplot3[samples y=0,samples=101,domain=0:3] ({1+cos(200*x)},{1+sin(200*x)},x);
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @ schrodinger's cat. I was actually updating my question while you were answering cause i thought; indeed, it's always possible to have a MWE :) Thank you.